# Getting issues when SQL is trying to write to table. Value Larger than Specific Precision

Tags: mysql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

So I work for a retail company and was involved in looking at an incident where I systemically had to 'load' some stock onto a trailer, to be dispatched to a store.

So I have an issue with some code which executed, the process is trying to do the following to a SQL table;

```
UPDATE RESV_LOCN_HDR SET RESV_LOCN_HDR.USER_ID = :1, RESV_LOCN_HDR.CURR_WT = :2, RESV_LOCN_HDR.CURR_VOL = :3, RESV_LOCN_HDR.CURR_UOM_QTY = :4, RESV_LOCN_HDR.MOD_DATE_TIME = :5 WHERE ( RESV_LOCN_HDR.LOCN_ID = :6 )

The input variables for reference are;
input variables
  1: Address(309adbdc) Length(0) Type(8) "RFUSER" - Indicator @ 309ad7d4 = 0
  2: Address(309ae02c) Length(0) Type(4) "11047.4" - Indicator @ 309ad9b8 = 0
  3: Address(309ae1ac) Length(0) Type(4) "-1.01e+09" - Indicator @ 309ada3c = 0
  4: Address(309ae32c) Length(0) Type(4) "-57" - Indicator @ 309adac0 = 0
  5: Address(309ae55c) Length(0) Type(7) "10/27/2016 2:57:50 PM" - Indicator @ 309adb70 = 0
  6: Address(309ade0c) Length(0) Type(8) "600062508" - Indicator @ 309ad8d0 = 0
```

The columns I am writing to (USER_ID, CURR_WT, CURR_VOL, CURR_UOM_QTY, MOD_DATE_TIME, LOCN_ID all have the following data types;

```
USER_ID = VARCHAR2(15 CHAR)
CURR_WT, CURR_VOL = NUMBER(13,4)
CURR_UOM_QTY = NUMBER(9,2)
MOD_DATE_TIME = DATE
LOCN_ID = VARCHAR2(10 CHAR)
```

From my understanding (and I'm sure you'll all see the above as well, all the column data types are met apart from 3: CURR_UOM_QTY is trying to write -1.01e+09, now is it just me or is this the reason why the error is being returned? Is it not that the above data is a macro? or something similar?

Just not seen SQL try to write 1.01e+09 before, as it should only be writing numerical data, not a mixture.

Using oracle 11g.

Comment: That is a numerical value. Google *scientific numeric notation*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the value of -1.01e+09 is why you are getting an error since your decimal precision is 4 and that value has many more decimals. It does not automatically round to four decimal places.